# Bootstrap: How to bring X icon for textbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i want to show X icon on textbox to clear textbox control's data. i tried this but not working properly.

X icon is not getting placed on textbox rather it is coming after textbox which is not right. so tell me what i am missing in code.

```
<div class="btn-group has-feedback has-clear">
    <input id="searchinput" type="search" class="form-control" style="width:200px;">
        <a 
id="searchclear" 
class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle form-control-feedback form-control-clear" 
style="pointer-events:auto; text-decoration:none; cursor:pointer;"
onclick="$(this).prev('input').val('');return false;">
</a>
</div>
```

jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/42173/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution. i've linked to Bootstrap v3.0.0, which didn't include the has-feedback classes.

Update my links to v3.3.7, and now code is working.

```
<div class="btn-group has-feedback">
    <input id="searchinput" type="search" class="form-control" style="width:200px;">
        <a 
id="searchclear" 
class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle form-control-feedback form-control-clear" 
style="pointer-events:auto; text-decoration:none; cursor:pointer;"
onclick="$(this).prev('input').val('');return false;">
</a>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/42200/